# Is it possible to get the original UUID1 from a timestamp?

Tags: random, timestamp, uuid

Say, for example, I generate a time based UUID with the following program.

```
import uuid
uuid = uuid.uuid1()
print uuid
print uuid.time
```

I get the following:

```
47702997-155d-11ea-92d3-6030d48747ec
137946228962896279
```

Can I get back the original UUID, that is `47702997-155d-11ea-92d3-6030d48747ec`, if I know the timestamp `(137946228962896279)`?

I am reading about UUID version 1 and found a few programs that "kind" of tries to reverses it, but, every time, I am getting a different UUID.

The part that is always changing are the timestamp part (last 4 digits of the first block - 47702997) and the clock_sequence (92d3).

If it is possible to get back the original UUID, what would I need?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This looks more a programing question, did you try to ask this on https://stackoverflow.com/ ?

Comment: Sorry, I realized later. I have posted it there as well.